# REST API interacting with Spark

Tags: python, node.js, rest, hadoop, apache-spark

I am trying to connect my Spark context with REST API. So my flow is this, i send request from my UI- nodejs to REST API which need to interact with the spark context ( Spark job works above hive tables ) which contains the needed response and send it back to UI for display. Is there any way to achieve this ?
UI <->REST API<-> Spark (HDFS)

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Apache Livy](http://livy.incubator.apache.org). It is specifically designed for this use case. We have used it in the past to control batch and regular jobs on a Spark cluster.

Comment: Thanks for this one. Will check on this .